# Clarification on the ng-checked directive

Tags: angularjs

I reference the document here: [ng-checked](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angChecked)

Here, at the example provided at the bottom of the page, you can see that clicking on the first checkbox also checks the second box.

The behaviour that I find with this is that even when the first checkbox is checked, the second checkbox can be unchecked - that is, after checking the first checkbox (the Master checkbox), the second checkbox gets checked automatically. If you now try to uncheck the second checkbox, it works which I find strange. The `ng-checked` directive is bound to the `master` model which is still `true`.

Why then is it possible to uncheck the second box? Shouldn't the `ng-checked` ensure that the checked state is always in sync with the expression - that is, shouldn't the ng-checked NOT allow the second checkbox to be unchecked as long as the first checkbox is still checked?

How does one manage to keep the second box checked as long as the master checkbox is checked?

Reference Code:

```html
Check me to check both: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="master">
<br/>
<!-- Expecting the following input to be checked as long as the master checkbox
     is checked / User should not be able to uncheck this as long as master
     is checked -->
<input id="checkSlave" type="checkbox" ng-checked="master">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ng-checked directive likely (I didn't examine the Angular source code) sets up a $watch on the `master` property.  Only when that property changes will the $watch fire.  So when you change the slave checkbox, the $watch doesn't fire, so the change happens.

If you want to keep the second checkbox in sync with the first, add an ng-model to the slave,

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="slave" ng-checked="master">
```

then force a sync anytime either model changes:

```
$scope.$watch(
   function() { return $scope.master + $scope.slave; }
  ,function() { $scope.slave = $scope.master; }
);
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yJAHt/)</kbd>

Note that this will also work:

```
$scope.$watch('master + slave', function() {
   $scope.slave = $scope.master;
});
```

Comment: For your information, you can see the confirmation of what Mark says in [the Angular source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d551d72924f7c43a043e4760ff05d7389e310f99/src/ng/directive/booleanAttrs.js#L343), where ```checked``` is [an element](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/fd87eb0ca5e14f213d8b31280d444dbc29c20c50/src/jqLite.js#L372) of ```BOOLEAN_ATTR```.

Comment: According to Misko, this is the incorrect approach, however, I am not sure how it can be accomplished solely with ng-model. Here is the link to his comments,  [master/slave checkboxes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1057). Any ideas how this could be accomplished without ng-checked?